# Custom View 1 AE

Tags: after-effects

How can i export a video in a custom view 1 perspective? When i always click the render button, it just always render to an active camera view.[image]

that is a 3d cube

Answer (score 0):

After effects renders the camera view, not the custom perspective views. To orient a camera as you would in the custom view go to camera view and choose the [unified camera tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/cameras-lights-points-interest.html#adjust_a_3d_view_or_move_a_camera_light_or_point_of_interest) (hit <kbd>c</kbd>). Now you can orbit (lmb-drag), pan (mmb-drag), and dolly (rmb-drag) the camera to get the perspective you want.